Uniform Integrability of $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ with $X_n\sim \operatorname{Bin}(n,\frac{1}{n})$
Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ with $X_n\sim \operatorname{Bin}(n,\frac{1}{n})$. I am trying to prove that for every $\epsilon >0$ we may find $k(\epsilon)\in\mathbb N$ s.t. for all $n\in\mathbb N$ we have $$\mathbb E[\lvert X_n\rvert\cdot 1_{\lvert X_n\rvert\geq k(\epsilon)}]\leq \epsilon.$$ We know that $X_n\to X$ in distribution with $X\sim\operatorname{Poi}(1)$ (by Le Cam's inequality we even have uniform convergence of the resp. probability mass functions).
Straightforward calculations and the triangle inequality yield $$\mathbb E[\lvert X_n\rvert\cdot 1_{\lvert X_n\rvert\geq k(\epsilon)}] \leq \sum_{i=k(\epsilon)}^n i\cdot \lvert \mathbb P(X_n = i) - \mathbb P(X=i)\rvert\:\: + \sum_{i=k(\epsilon)}^\infty i\cdot \mathbb P(X=i).$$ How to handle the second term is clear to me. However, the first one poses a problem as I don't see how to make this small with large $k(\epsilon)$. The convergence rate I would get from Le Cam's Inequality is not sufficient for this I think.
Any help is appreciated.

One has
$$
\mathbb E\left[X_n^2\right]=\operatorname{Var}(X_n)+\left(\mathbb E[X_n]\right)^2=n\frac 1n\left(1-\frac 1n\right)+1^2=2-\frac 1{n},
$$
in particular, $\sup_{n\geqslant 1}\mathbb E\left[X_n^2\right]$ is finite, which is a sufficient condition for uniform integrability since
$$
\mathbb E\left[X_n\mathbf{1}_{X_n>k(\varepsilon)}\right]
\leqslant \mathbb E\left[X_n\frac{X_n}{k(\varepsilon)}\mathbf{1}_{X_n>k(\varepsilon)}\right]\leqslant\frac 1{k(\varepsilon)}\mathbb E\left[X_n^2\right]\leqslant \frac 2{k(\varepsilon)}.
$$

Beautiful, thank you!
